# order by and rownum in inner query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-order-by, rownum

I've 2 linked tables A an B 1 to n

For all records of A I'd like to have the record of B matching the following conditions

- A.dep=B.dep
- There is no record in B having the same year of A
- I want the maching record of B with the year beeing the latest year before the year of A
- If There is more than one record take the one with the latest updateDate
- If There is more than one record take the one with the latest creationDate
- If There is more than one record take the one with the latest Id

I tried the Following

```
Select ...
from A
     ...
     left join B same on A.dep=same.dep and A.year=same.year
     left join B last on A.dep=last.dep and A.year>last.year
where ...
      and same.id is null
      and (last.id is null or
           last.id = (select id from B where dep=A.dep and rownum=1 order by year desc, updateDate desc, creationDate desc, id desc))
```

But I've an error :

```
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

But all the parenthesis are ok.
Looks like the inner select doesn't support the order by

Any idea?

Comment: if you use aliases, that you also should it use  in your conditions  e.g. `A.dep=same.dep` instead of `A.dep=B.dep`

Comment: Yes thanks it's a typo

Answer (score 0):

It is `ORDER BY` in a subquery.

If you run it in SQL*Plus (or some tool that *shows* error position), you'd get

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept d
  3  where 1 = 1
  4    and d.deptno = (select e.deptno from emp e where e.ename = 'KING' order by e.sal);
  and d.deptno = (select e.deptno from emp e where e.ename = 'KING' order by e.sal)
                                                                    *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

So:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept d
  3  where 1 = 1
  4    and d.deptno = (select e.deptno from emp e where e.ename = 'KING');

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK

SQL>
```

Comment: How to fix what? Remove order by, it is irrelevant in this context.

Comment: Irrelevant in your query but in mine I'm using rownum=1 to retrieve the more recent record

Comment: Use ROWNUM or RANK analytic function, not ORDER BY + ROWNUM.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, inner sub-query does not support order by because it will give a partial resultset which will be manipulated further by the outer query.

Use order by to sort the result based on your requirements once the resultset corresponding to other filter conditions is obtained.

So, in your case, get the query to match your filter conditions first and then apply order by based on the requirements. But, if you do want the inner sub-query results to be ordered first before applying it to outer/main query, use a join. Create a resultset based on the inner sub-query first and join it with an alias to the other/main query results with appropriate join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `b.id` is unique, you can do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     b
     on b.dep = a.dep and
        b.year <= a.year and
        b.id = (select max(b2.id) keep (dense_rank first order by b2.year desc, b2.updatedate desc, b2.creationdate desc, b2.id desc)
                from b b2
                where b2.dep = b.dep 
               );
```